# how to create an alternative tmp directory?

Tags: linux

`mktemp` has an option to use `$TMPDIR` to locate new temp files/dirs. For my application I would like to not use `/tmp` because it is mounted on `/` which has precious little space. I would rather have my scripts go to something like `/app-name/tmp`.

How do I create such a temp directory so that it is automatically cleaned up on reboot?

When I run `ls -ld /tmp` I get the following output, showing a "t" at end. What does that "t" mean? Is this the key to automatic cleanup on reboot?

```
$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 32 root root 2072576 Feb  1 18:37 /tmp
```

I am using SLES 11 SP3.

```
$ uname -a
Linux XYZ 3.0.101-0.47.71-default #1 SMP Thu Nov 12 12:22:22 UTC 2015 (b5b212e) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Why don't you mount some volume on `/tmp`, thus removing that limitation which is the cause here?

Comment: that sounds like a good option, thanks. But I have a ton of capacity already on other volumes. Another factor is that I am on AWS and use a "preapproved" template to launch this server, so getting them to change that template may be complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke your app (assuming you're using standard apis for temp files) with `TMPDIR=/app-name/tmp start_my_app` and mount a device that has space at /app-name/tmp

The "t" in the mode is the sticky bit, it has nothing to do with temp. You can read about the sticky bit, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit).

To have the folder emptied you can either you use a tmpfs (if you have low volume) or add something in your init, or use crontab.

Comment: ++ for demystifying "t". how to get this dir get cleaned up on reboot?

Comment: @Dinesh Either you use a tmpfs (if we have low volume) or add something in your init, or use crontab

Comment: Can you please edit your answer from comment so that it is complete to a new reader

Answer (score 0):

The cleaning of tmp is not done automatically by the system, it's a script in the boot process.

If you want to do cleaning of another directory do the same, a good place to clean your tmp directory could be /etc/rc.local (for example).